# Default/Inbuilt database for windows phone 7

Tags: database, windows-phone-7, c#-4.0, sqlite

Iam new to windows phone programming. Please suggest,what is default/inbuilt database to used to store data for windows phone 7.
I have searched and found SQLite. Is it fine or i need to go with some other database??

Answer (score 0):

either sqlite or isolatedstorage but isolatedstorage isn't a real database

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 option to storing data in WP7.

- External server - using webservice you push the data to the server
- WP7 [SQL CE](http://windowsphonegeek.com/tips/Windows-Phone-Mango-Local-Database%28SQL-CE%29-Introduction) - using LINQ to SQL store the data locally.
- IsolatedStorage - store data as a file

As far I'm aware SQLite is only available for Windows Phone 8.

Comment: Though the libraries haven't been updated in a while, C#Sqlite does work on WP7: http://code.google.com/p/csharp-sqlite/

Comment: @MichaelItzoe of course, any database that can run with .Net CF can run on WP7, but they are not supported.